# 'ps' and 'top' show different memory usage for single process

Tags: memory

When I do 'ps -auxwww', it shows X using about 342M of memory.

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND 
[...] 
root      2009  1.0  5.1 342564 105012 tty7    Rs+  Oct08 469:24 X :0 
[...]
```

However, 'top' shows about 1358M:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND 
[...] 
 2009 root      20   0 1358m 102m  14m S  0.3  5.1 469:24.27 X 
[...]
```

Why, and which one is correct?

I've seen posts re 'top' and 'ps' "total memory used" being different 
(because of shared memory), but not why this would happen on a single 
process.

EDIT: it turns out that even none of the "ps -eo" options will give what top gives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Top includes what's cached in buffers and whatnot.  PS does not.  If you want your actual usage by the application, use ps.  If you want the total used by the application including what the system reserves for it ..  use top

Comment: OK, but if top shows 1358M, does it mean those 1358M aren't available to any other process?

Comment: Correct, because even though `ps` is showing less physical usage (342M), look at the percent of memory usage, it's the same. `5.1%`  `ps` is just letting you know what the `process` is using, not the `process + system for process reserve`  --  Go by TOP if you want to  know how much is left for use by other applications.

Comment: I don't suppose there's any way to tell a process "don't reserve more memory that you need, you memory hog!"

Comment: Certain apps will allow for that in config files, but mostly "it is what it is"  lol